# I am not sure what is wrong but every time I launch terminal this comes up. How should I fix it?

Tags: macos

The error:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: initsite: Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sahaj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'os'
```

My .bash_profile:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
# added by Anaconda3 2018.12 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/sahaj/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/sahaj/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/sahaj/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/sahaj/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
# added by Anaconda3 2019.03 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

Comment: In the start-up sequence, there is a python script that is missing modules. To debug this, you should look at  `.bashrc` (assuming you use bash). Add the content of `.bashrc` to your question, please.

Comment: @LjmDullaart I added it.

Comment: That's the output of a `ls ~`. Ljm Dullaart wants the output of a `cat .bashrc`.. wait, you don't have a .bashrc file? I can't find it in your ls output. What shell do you use? zsh? fish?

Comment: @LjmDullaart I am sorry I do not understand what you want

Comment: I just looked it up, the MacOS equivalent of .bashrc is .bash_profile, which you have. Do `cat .bash_profile` and give us the output of that.

Comment: I added it! @udlp